# TestFlight build started testing but email link brings up blank screen in TestFlight App

Tags: ios, testflight

I am a developer and internal tester for me organization (me). I just uploaded a new build to iTunes Connect, the build processed, I added it to TestFlight for internal testers. I received the email for this build being available in TestFlight, clicked on the embedded link on the email, TestFlight app opened, but NO builds are shown.  Just a blank screen and a message that a developer has to invite me.  This has never happened to me before.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this?
[image: email from Testflight]

[image: image in TestFlight app]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that another internal tester did get a TestFlight email with the build attached.  It looks like TestFlight won't send the build if the developer and the tester's apple id are the same.  Weird!